# Mysql alternativ for join same table multiple time

Tags: mysql

I used the following query to get data, but now i need to join the same table 4 or more time again, so i want to find the alternate way.

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t2.name as name2,t3.name as name3,t4.name as name4....
FROM first_table as t1
left join second_table as t2 on t2.code = t1.f_name,
left join second_table as t3 on t3.code = t1.l_name,
left join second_table as t4 on t4.code = t1.a_name,
.......
.....
.....
```

and many joins so how can i get the same result in a better way(efficient)?

Comment: why you need to join the same table multiple times? it might be possible to use just one join, but it depends on the context...

Comment: because i have multiple columns in first table that has relation with same column of second table for example t1.f_name is 123 and the related real name for f_name=123 is in column of name of second_table and same criteria for l_name and a_name of first_table

Comment: please search for how to do recursive queries in MySQL. There are several approaches, none really trivial. Come back for help if you get stuck.

Comment: your query is correct, but it really depends on the context, e.g. you could join `first_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN second_table AS t2 ON t2.code IN (t1.f_name, t1.l_name, t1.a_name)` and you might use GROUP_CONCAT if it returns multiple rows, but it depends on what's the logic behind your database structure

Comment: @fthiella i want to take second_table.name as f_name if second_table.code = t1.f_name else if second_table.code = t1.l_name then get second_table.name as l_name. But if i use IN how can i distinguish which one is f_name,l_name,etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this query:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.f_name THEN t2.name END) AS name2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.l_name THEN t2.name END) AS name3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.a_name THEN t2.name END) AS name4
FORM
  first_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN second_table AS t2
  ON t2.code IN (t1.f_name, t1.l_name, t1.a_name)
GROUP BY
  t1.id,
  t1.name
```